# Translating an equation from multiplicative to additive form

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The equation I have is 
$ \big(ab^{2}\big) ^{-3}c^{2}=***e***$

which is in multiplicative form but which I am trying to convert it to additive form.
e is the identity element

Here's what I have so far

$[-(ab^{2})]+[-(ab^{2})]+[-(ab^{2})]+c+c=e$
$ \Rightarrow [-(a+(b+b))]+[-(a+(b+b))]+[-(a+(b+b))]+c+c=e$

$\Rightarrow [-a-b-b]+[-a-b-b]+[-a-b-b]+c+c=e$

$ \Rightarrow -3a-6b+2c=e$

Could someone verify the my solution?

Comment: What is six stars above indicate?

Comment: Is your group Abelian?

Comment: @QuảnBáHồngNguyễn Ignore the stars. It was meant to indicate the identity element e as bold and italic.

Comment: @Babaxor Treat addition as commutative. So yes, the group is Abelian.

Answer (score 0):

The identity above is equivalent ${c^2} = {\left( {a{b^2}} \right)^3}e$

"Transform" multiplication to addition, we have $c + c = 3\left( {a + b + b} \right) + e$. Like your result. But we also have $e + x = x + e = x$, for any element $x$ in group ($e$ here is in addition).

So we get $3a+6b=2c$

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why there is a need to add the element x to e.

Comment: oh. that is a property of group. I just rewrite to use it for $x=3(a+a+b)$ in your problem.